# VAST version when using <Ad>s from different VAST responses

Tags: vast, iab

What VAST@version value should be used when combining s from different VAST responses, with different VAST versions?

Say there are 2 VAST responses:
Response 1 has VAST@version 4.0.

```
<VAST ... version="4.0>"
  <Ad ... id="1">
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Response 2 has VAST@version 3.0.

```
<VAST ... version="3.0>"
  <Ad ... id="2">
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Each response contains an  element.  If the  elements are going to be combined in a separate  element, what should that VAST element's version value be?

```
<VAST ... version=?>
  <Ad ... id="1">
  </Ad>
  <Ad ... id="2">
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

The  element is required for VAST 4.0 onwards, but not for VAST 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The version should be "4.0" if the first Ad is using any features from "4.0". What you would really need to do is parse the entire vast document and determine which features are used from the different versions of vast and then select the highest version. For example, if there is a UniversalAdId or if there are any of the newer tracking events.